# How to find and retrieve video content in a pdf file via mupdf library for Android

Tags: android, pdf, video, mupdf

I need to check if a Richmedia content (video embedded in a pdf file) is available in a pdf file or not via mupdf library for an android application.

If it is then I need to retrieve the stream content via pdf parsing and convert in to a byte array and run the video found in the pdf.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

MuPDF does not support embedded video. You can still use the library to examine the PDF object structure and extract data streams from PDF files. Look at the "pdfshow" and "pdfextract" tools for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [iText for android](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextpdfandroid/), although it seems to be a constrained version. There is a post on how to extract media objects from pdf files with iText [here](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Extracting-embedded-media-object-from-Pdf-td2162945.html).

Comment: Thanks dude, Is there any proper iText version for android application.I couldnt run the iText version properly.

Comment: The link I posted is supposed to work on android, but with a few missing functionalities according to the project description. Is that the one you tried? By the way, taking a quick look into mupdf source codes, it does not seem to support rendition objects (the pdf objects containing embedded videos), so I think you will not be able to use it for this task.

Comment: Are u sure that mupdf does not support embedded videos?